# How can I install vagrant plugins on win8

Tags: rubygems, vagrant, virtualbox

I haveinstalled vagrant(1.7.4) and virtualbox(5.0.2) on windows, then I downloaded precise32.box and put in inside the folder named vag_pre. After I entered this command line:vagrant up, it occured warning. Here is the codes:

```
Think@RESEARCH E:\vag_pre
$ vagrant box add base precise32.box
==> box: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
==> box: Adding box 'base' (v0) for provider:
    box: Unpacking necessary files from: file://E:/vag_pre/precise32.box
    box: Progress: 100% (Rate: 2588k/s, Estimated time remaining: --:--:--)
==> box: Successfully added box 'base' (v0) for 'virtualbox'!

Think@RESEARCH E:\vag_pre
$ ls
precise32.box

Think@RESEARCH E:\vag_pre
$ vagrant init
A `Vagrantfile` has been placed in this directory. You are now
ready to `vagrant up` your first virtual environment! Please read
the comments in the Vagrantfile as well as documentation on
`vagrantup.com` for more information on using Vagrant.

Think@RESEARCH E:\vag_pre
$ ls
precise32.box  Vagrantfile

Think@RESEARCH E:\vag_pre
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'base'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: vag_pre_default_1441356586862_57133
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default:
    default: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
    default: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
    default:
    default: Inserting generated public key within guest...
    default: Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present...
    default: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    default: The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of
    default: VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
    default: prevent things such as shared folders from working properly. If you see
    default: shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions within the
    default: virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have installed on
    default: your host and reload your VM.
    default:
    default: Guest Additions Version: 4.2.0
    default: VirtualBox Version: 5.0
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => E:/vag_pre

Think@RESEARCH E:\vag_pre
$ vagrant plugin update vagrant-vbguest
Updating plugins: vagrant-vbguest. This may take a few minutes...
Bundler, the underlying system Vagrant uses to install plugins,
reported an error. The error is shown below. These errors are usually
caused by misconfigured plugin installations or transient network
issues. The error from Bundler is:

An error occurred while installing little-plugger (1.1.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install little-plugger -v '1.1.4'` succeeds before bundling.

Warning: this Gemfile contains multiple primary sources. Using `source` more than once without a block is a security risk, and may result in installing unexpected gems. To resolve this warning, use a block to indicate which gems should come from the secondary source. To upgrade this warning to an error, run `bundle config disable_multisource true`.Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: Errno::ECONNRESET: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. - SSL_connect (https://rubygems.org/gems/little-plugger-1.1.4.gem)
```

And I don't know how to install gem on win8.1, should I install ruby first? Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install a new plugin you need to  run `vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest`.

as it seems you're having an issue with the ssl connection to https://rubygems.org, you should add the following parameter :

`vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest --plugin-source http://rubygems.org`

Comment: Think@RESEARCH E:\vag_pre
$ vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest
Installing the 'vagrant-vbguest' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
Bundler, the underlying system Vagrant uses to install plugins,
reported an error. The error is shown below. These errors are usually
caused by misconfigured plugin installations or transient network
issues. The error from Bundler is:

Comment: sorry, it is a little long,

Comment: An error occurred while installing little-plugger (1.1.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install little-plugger -v '1.1.4'` succeeds before bundling.

Warning: this Gemfile contains multiple primary sources. Using `source` more than once without a block is a security risk, and may result in installing unexpected gems. To resolve this warning, use a block to indicate which gems should come from the secondary source.

Comment: To upgrade this warning to an error, run `bundle config disable_multisource true`.Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: Errno::ECONNRESET: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. - SSL_connect (https://rubygems.org/gems/little-plugger-1.1.4.gem)

Comment: weird it does not seem like it is using this gem. if you have installed a previous version of plugin can you try to uninstall first, then install.

Comment: also does `vagrant plugin update` gives the same error ?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @codexer, you're right, I first thought it was an issue with the `install` vs `update` parameter. Giving another look and updating my answer, this should really solve the issue

Comment: @Frederic, sorry for my late replay as I had classes. 'vagrant plugin update' gave the same error, it said 'Make sure that `gem install little-plugger -v '1.1.4'` succeeds before bundling.' as before. Any other mathods?Or should I insall gem? I don't know how to install.Thanks very much for you attention,thanks

Comment: @YongqiZ, did you look my update ? `vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest --plugin-source http://rubygems.org` should work as it seems you have an issue with access of the https site.

Comment: @Frederic, sorry I did not see you update. Now I tried it and installed the plugin 'vagrant-vbguest' sucessfully, thank you very much

Comment: sorry, the errors occured one after another, I hope you don't mind my another question.after I install the vagrant-vbguest. I made a new folder and entered the command lines as follow, returned :'stdin: is not a tty' and 'GuestAdditions versions on your host (5.0.2) and guest (4.2.0) do not match.' and 'Could not find the X.Org or XFree86 Window System, skipping.'. As the information is too much,so I had to paste it on another page(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32410880/could-not-find-the-x-org-or-xfree86-window-system-skipping). I am a novice. Thanks very much