# Could not find the X.Org or XFree86 Window System, skipping

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I made a new folder to install virtualbox, vagrant is 1.7.4, the virtualbox is 5.0.2. And have installed vagrant-vbguest sucessfully. I saw the errors below,it mainly said 'stdin is not a tty', and 'Could not find the X.Org or XFree86 Window System, skipping'. I have installed git, and have the id_rsa and id_rsa.pub in .ssh folder. I did this on win8.1. Thanks very much

```
Think@RESEARCH E:\vag_new
> vagrant box add newbase precise32.box
==> box: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
==> box: Adding box 'newbase' (v0) for provider:
    box: Unpacking necessary files from: file://E:/vag_new/precise32.box
    box: Progress: 100% (Rate: 17.5M/s, Estimated time remaining: --:--:--)
==> box: Successfully added box 'newbase' (v0) for 'virtualbox'!

Think@RESEARCH E:\vag_new
> vagrant init
A `Vagrantfile` has been placed in this directory. You are now
ready to `vagrant up` your first virtual environment! Please read
the comments in the Vagrantfile as well as documentation on
`vagrantup.com` for more information on using Vagrant.

Think@RESEARCH E:\vag_new
> ls
precise32.box  Vagrantfile

Think@RESEARCH E:\vag_new
> vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'base'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: vag_new_default_1441436421015_28742
==> default: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2200.
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 2200 (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2200
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default:
    default: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
    default: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
    default:
    default: Inserting generated public key within guest...
    default: Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present...
    default: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
GuestAdditions versions on your host (5.0.2) and guest (4.2.0) do not match.
stdin: is not a tty
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following extra packages will be installed:
  fakeroot linux-headers-3.2.0-23 make patch
Suggested packages:
  make-doc diffutils-doc
Recommended packages:
  linux-headers-generic-pae linux-headers-686-pae linux-headers-amd64
  linux-headers-generic linux-headers
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dkms fakeroot linux-headers-3.2.0-23 linux-headers-3.2.0-23-generic-pae make
  patch
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 66 not upgraded.
Need to get 12.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 68.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main make i386 3.81-8.1ubuntu1 [116 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main patch i386 2.6.1-3 [86.0 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main dkms all 2.2.0.3-1ubuntu3 [73.1 kB]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main fakeroot i386 1.18.2-1 [87.9 kB]
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main linux-headers-3.2.0-23 all 3.2.0-23.36 [11.4 MB]
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main linux-headers-3.2.0-23-generic-pae i386 3.2.0-23.36
 [944 kB]
dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin: No such file or directory
Fetched 12.7 MB in 14min 34s (14.6 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package make.
(Reading database ... 29361 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking make (from .../make_3.81-8.1ubuntu1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package patch.
Unpacking patch (from .../patch_2.6.1-3_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package dkms.
Unpacking dkms (from .../dkms_2.2.0.3-1ubuntu3_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package fakeroot.
Unpacking fakeroot (from .../fakeroot_1.18.2-1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-3.2.0-23.
Unpacking linux-headers-3.2.0-23 (from .../linux-headers-3.2.0-23_3.2.0-23.36_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-3.2.0-23-generic-pae.
Unpacking linux-headers-3.2.0-23-generic-pae (from .../linux-headers-3.2.0-23-generic-pae_3.2.0-23.36_i386.
deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up make (3.81-8.1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up patch (2.6.1-3) ...
Setting up dkms (2.2.0.3-1ubuntu3) ...
Setting up fakeroot (1.18.2-1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/fakeroot-sysv to provide /usr/bin/fakeroot (fakeroot) in auto mode.
Setting up linux-headers-3.2.0-23 (3.2.0-23.36) ...
Setting up linux-headers-3.2.0-23-generic-pae (3.2.0-23.36) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 3.2.0-23-generic-pae /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-23-generic
-pae
Copy iso file C:\Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso into the box /tmp/VBoxGuestAddition
s.iso
stdin: is not a tty
mount: warning: /mnt seems to be mounted read-only.
Installing Virtualbox Guest Additions 5.0.2 - guest version is 4.2.0
stdin: is not a tty
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing VirtualBox 5.0.2 Guest Additions for Linux............
VirtualBox Guest Additions installer
Removing installed version 4.2.0 of VirtualBox Guest Additions...
Copying additional installer modules ...
Installing additional modules ...
Removing existing VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Removing existing VirtualBox non-DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Building the VirtualBox Guest Additions kernel modules ...done.
Doing non-kernel setup of the Guest Additions ...done.
You should restart your guest to make sure the new modules are actually used

Installing the Window System drivers
Could not find the X.Org or XFree86 Window System, skipping.
An error occurred during installation of VirtualBox Guest Additions 5.0.2. Some functionality may not work
as intended.
In most cases it is OK that the "Window System drivers" installation failed.
stdin: is not a tty
Restarting VM to apply changes...
==> default: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2200
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    default: The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of
    default: VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
    default: prevent things such as shared folders from working properly. If you see
    default: shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions within the
    default: virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have installed on
    default: your host and reload your VM.
    default:
    default: Guest Additions Version: 4.2.0
    default: VirtualBox Version: 5.0
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => E:/vag_new
```

Comment: can you run `vagrant vbguest --status` and show the output

Comment: yes, it returns 'GuestAdditions 5.0.2 running --- OK.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the install have been done correctly - the same issue has been reported at https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest/issues/130

you can download the `VBoxGuestAdditions.iso` file at http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.0.0/ and replace the existing file under your installed virtual box (not sure about the path under windows; would be /VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso for mac users)

Comment: After I replace the file(the path is C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox) , I got almost the same return 'stdin: is not a tty
/sbin/mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: No such device', anyway thank you very much.

Comment: `stdin: is not a tty` is not an error, just for information. after the file change, does the plugin reports that the versions are different ?

Comment: yes, 'GuestAdditions versions on your host (5.0.2) and guest (4.2.0) do not match.'.    Not any other errors

Comment: "stdin: is not a tty" is a problem I get with VirtualBox in GUI environments also -- you have to run the guest additions tool using /bin/bash /mount/cdrom0/VirtualBox.sh or whatever -- my path is wrong, but you must run it with bash manually.  Not sure if that fixes this issue, but it does fix the `stdin: is not a tty` iirc